# how to send approval email thru Workflow which can read more than one persons in ( persons and group) feild

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, people-picker, approval-process

I have one field of (person / group) or people picker box in info path form library, and I apply the setting to accept more than one person at the same time in check boxes, and I want to design a workflow in the designer to let the user enter for more than one person address and I want to send an email to both of them in parallel way.

But the problem is the sharepoint doesn’t recognize the second name or address, it work perfect just for the first name.